# best way to handle orientation change with bluetooth sockets

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-orientation

I'm creating an app that has a bluetooth connection.  I've created a library that uses callbacks every time a connection is lost/failed/established/etc.  Everything about the connection works just fine, but I'm having a hard time handling orientation changes.  I want the connection to remain open when the device changes orientation.  At the same time I want the connection to close when the user closes the application.  The API levels I'm designing this for are APIs 5-10.  Here's the issues I come across:

1. If I close my connection on `onDestroy()`, the connection will close every time the app is closed but not when the app is simply paused (desired output).  However, `onDestroy()` is called whenever the application orientation changes.  Which leads to issue #2.
2. If I use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, I can successfully keep the open socket.  If I don't close the socket in `onDestroy()`, then everything works just fine.  However, the socket seems to remain open when the app closes (i.e. the other devices are still reading from it).

The setup I currently have looks similar to this:

```
BluetoothConnection btConnection;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
   /** Activity setup **/

   btConnection = (BluetoothConnection) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
   if(btConnection != null) // we already have a connection from a previous state, let's set it up to work with this state
   {
      /** Set up the connection since it already exists **/
   }
}

@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
{
   BluetoothConnection saveConnection = btConnection;
   return saveConnection;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
   super.onDestroy()
   if(btConnection != null)
      btConnection.closeConnection();
}
```

With this current implementation, the socket will be saved but closed at the same time `because both onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` is called as well as `onDestroy()`.

I guess I'd like to know two things:

1. Is `onRetainNonConfigrationInstance()` a good way to handle this problem to begin with?
2. Is there a more elegant way to keep a connection open till an app closes?  I've thought about creating a boolean like onRetainCalled to prevent the thing from closing, but it seems ugly to me (and possibly unreliable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimally, you should put your Bluetooth connection code into a `Service`: I use this and it is quite excellent. You can open multiple Activities without having to think about it at all.

Comment: It seems so simple now.  Thanks.